# Nginx + Reverse Proxy + PrestaShop

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx

I am facing a problem with setting up Nginx as a reverse proxy for Apache2, which serves Prestashop content.

Nginx /sites-available/*.conf:

```
    server {
       listen 80 default_server;
       listen [::]:80;
       server_name example.com www.example.com

       location / {
          proxy_set_header Host &host;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded_proto $scheme;
          proxy_set_header http://0.0.0.0:8081;
       }
}
```

Apache2 /sites-available/*.conf:

```
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:8081>
     ServerAdmin admin@yexample.com
      DocumentRoot /var/www/html/prestashop
     ServerName example.com

     <Directory /var/www/html/prestashop>
          Options FollowSymlinks
          AllowOverride All
          Require all granted
     </Directory>

     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com_error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is, when I hit `example.com` in my browser, it indeed redirects me to  my shop, but in URL my DNS(example.com) changes to my server's IP + port instantly. 
I did some tests of my Presta using my server's IP before deployment - maybe that be the cause of the problem. The IP browser shows is the IP that I used during tests.

I also changed IP addresses in .htaccess file in Presta root dir, but that does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the base URL properly in the Presta Shop configuration.

From [the documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS17/Setting+a+shop%27s+URL):

> To add a URL to a shop, select the shop in the "Multistore tree" selector, and then click on the "Add new URL" button.

Setting the `Main URL` option seems like what you want to do.